# Why should we adhere w3 standards while developing webpages?

Tags: html, css, web

In the UI development area there has been lot of emphasis on adhering w3 standards. I have very basic question why the webpages should adhere w3 standards. My specific questions are

(1) What are the top 10 reasons adhere w3 standards?
(2) What are the top 10 issues I will get if I don't adhere to w3 standards even though web page I have developed working fine?

Comment: Questions that are **too broad** or **primarily opinion based** are unfortunately off topic here.

Comment: Would it hurt  adhering to w3 ??

Comment: @JoshC May I ask: is there a place where they're **on** topic (within the stackexchange network)?

Comment: @jerdiggity There are no other places - questions like these aren't accepted.. I assume that is because there is no definite answer.. this question already has 3 close votes.

Comment: @JoshC I was just wondering if there was a place... Not contesting the validity of the reasoning behind closing it. :)

Comment: @jerdiggity Actually, the chat rooms are good places for questions like these.

Comment: @JoshC: How come I know question is too broad before posting? Any thoughts or ideas? And I have edited the question will it suffice to narrow down answers? Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

As a web developer, adhering to w3 standards is **strongly** recommended, simply because browsers implement those standards. Without standards imagine IE 6-7 like stylesheets for every browser out there.

By coding to standards we do our but in giving users accross platform, browsers and screens that will get a uniform experience, that said there are a few things that browsers render differently. But with IE 9, Internet Explorer also started falling in line with other browsers.

Also, there are ton of libraries and frameworks that assume you have valid markup to work properly.

Just a demo, try and remove `doctype` declaration and open your site in IE.

Answer (score 0):

See this link for info about HTML validation: http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#why-validate

I also like their saying *WYSINWOG - **What You See Is Not What Others Get*** because it's so true (a lot of the time, at least).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question could possibly become a list, but the primary reason that stands out for me is **compliance**.

Your site may look fine to you among the browsers you are able to test on, but if you start to go outside the standards the chances of it working in browsers that you couldn't test goes down.

There's lots of browsers available today on an increasingly broad spectrum of devices with multiple versions available. Its just not possible to test everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your webpages against the w3 validator at http://validator.w3.org/

As for WHY keeping your pages up to standards is because those standards are there for a reason.

Your pages work fine for you.  Have you tested how the pages look / perform in all browsers? IE 8+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, SeaMonkey, etc.?  Are you 100% sure your website is handicapped accessible?

When developers adhere to w3 standards, and browsers adhere to w3 standards, then the chance that users will have a consistent experience regardless of what browser they use increases.  Visitors who don't have an ideal experience won't return.  Adhering to the w3 standards increases the odds in your favor of a visitor having a positive experience, thereby increasing the chances that they will return.

One of the first things I learned when I started developing webpages/sites was to never let the phrase "It works on MY machine" be part of my professional vocabulary (except in jest).  It doesn't matter how much a dev likes something or how well they perceive something to work - all that matters is the user's experience.  If you have to bend over backwards to make the user's experience enjoyable then so be it - they are the ones who write the checks after all.